# Count function returning null

Tags: sqlite

I am having an issue with the count function where the count function returns a null value

I have four tables

1. controls(ruid, ratc_id, raw_value, value, min, max, translate_id, unit, monitor, changed)
2. events (ruid, event_id, min, max, current_status, previous_status)
3. event_log (ruid, event_id, raw_value, TIMESTAMP)
4. Monitors

I am having an issue with the count function. Here is a part of my code

```
create temp table Testing_table as

select event_log.[ruid] as ruid, event_log.[raw_value] as raw_value, event_log.[event_id] as event_id, event_log.[timestamp] as timestamp, count ('Test_ID') as 'Test_ID', null as 'Test Result'
from event_log
JOIN controls
on event_log.[ruid] = controls.[ruid]
and event_log.[raw_value] = controls.[raw_value]
UNION
select
ruid, raw_value, event_id, timestamp, null as 'Test_ID',

CASE 
when raw_value = 0.9343453535635 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.04583743847 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.563363656757 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.6666666666 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.65757447777 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.9267482727372 then 'Pass'

when raw_value = 0.2323239945454 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.9732746367437 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.0222222222222 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.5656857676747 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.6546456363563 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.0348343874738 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.9457458745737 then 'Pass'

when raw_value = 0.543452434345 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.9836438454522 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.2546456745635 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.0456474635353 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.9454545454256 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.0456474635353 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.4536465665635 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.4536465665635 then 'Pass'
when raw_value = 0.4545465752726 then 'Pass'

when ruid = 2 then 'Not in events_log'
when ruid = 4 then 'Not in events_log'

else 'Failed'

end 
 as 'Test Result'
 from event_log;
 select * from Testing_table;
```

Here is the query result:

```
ruid    raw_value   event_id    timestamp        Test_ID     Test Result 
1   0.04583743847   1   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass
1   0.563363656757  1   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass
1   0.9267482727372 1   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass
3   0.0222222222222 2   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass
3   0.0348343874738 2   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass
3   0.2323239945454 2   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass 
3   0.5656857676747 2   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass
3   0.9457458745737 2   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass
3   0.9457458745737 2   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  2          <null>
3   0.9732746367437 2   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass
5   0.0456474635353 3   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass
5   0.2546456745635 3   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass
5   0.4536465665635 3   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass
5   0.9454545454256 3   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass
5   0.9836438454522 3   2014-03-06 13:33:52.187  <null>         Pass
```

How would I get the Test_ID column to go up by one for each row?

Hope this all makes sense.

Comment: COUNT never returns NULL. You are getting NULL because you explicitly write NULL in your SELECT.

Comment: Ok, how would I get the query result to produce the result I want. I would like the test_id to go up in steps of one so that I can order the table by the Test_id.

Comment: And how should it determine which result record gets which test_id?

Comment: I was hoping the Test_ID column would get the test ID, but I'm not sure how it would determine which result would get the test ID